# How do I use <Link> to perform an action similar to " window.location = "/GameOverDied"; " in JS React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, jsx, react-router-dom

Currently I am trying to do some animation transitions with a game I'm building in React and I don't want the re-render/refresh function of `href` or `window.location`. How would I use `<Link>` from `react-router-dom` handled in this regard?

```js
const handleGameOver = () => {
  if (health < 1) {
    window.location = "/GameOverDied";
  } else if (fuel < 1) {
    window.location = "/GameOverFuel";
  } else {
  }
};
```

I haven't tried anything yet because I'm not getting the answers I was looking for anywhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Link` is a React component and would need to be rendered to have any effect in the UI as a ***declarative*** navigation action. Use the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook instead to issue an ***imperative*** navigation action from a callback.

Example:

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const handleGameOver = () => {
  if (health < 1) {
    navigate("/GameOverDied", { replace: true });
  } else if (fuel < 1) {
    navigate("/GameOverFuel", { replace: true });
  } else {
  }
};

...
```